# Polarization surface charge density on spherical surface - electromagnetics

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, polarization

### Problem

> A charged metal sphere of radius $a $ gives rise to a $\mathbf{D} $-field given by $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{a_R} \frac{C}{R^2} $ in the surrounding medium with permittivity $\varepsilon $. What is the polarization surface charge density at the spherical surface $R=a $?
>
> [image]

### Attempt

We know the relationship $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{D}-\varepsilon_0\mathbf{E}=(\varepsilon-\varepsilon_0)\mathbf{E} $.

Recalling that $\mathbf{E}= \frac{\mathbf{D}}{\varepsilon} $ gives
$$ \mathbf{P}= \frac{(\varepsilon-\varepsilon_0) \mathbf{D}}{\varepsilon}=\frac{(\varepsilon-\varepsilon_0) C}{\varepsilon a^2}$$

We also have this relationship $\rho_{\text{ps}}=\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{a_n} $, where $\mathbf{a_n} $ is the outward normal vector.

### Questions

It turns out the correct answer to this problem is b), so $\rho_{\text{ps}}= -\frac{(\varepsilon-\varepsilon_0) C}{\varepsilon a^2}$ but I don't understand this. The minus-sign must mean that one has to choose a normal vector that points opposite of $\mathbf{P} $, but why?

Also, the minus-sign assures that the surface charge density is a negative number, but how can a **density** be negative? I hope someone can clarify this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The "outward normal" for a dielectric object is the vector pointing out of the volume of the object.  In this case, since you have a dielectric surrounding a metal sphere, the "outward normal" points from the dielectric into the center of the sphere, and so the outward normal is $-\hat{r}$.

2. Charge density $\rho$ is defined to be charge per volume.  If you have a negative charge in some volume, then $\rho$ is negative.

Comment: Ahh okay. Finally I understand it. Thank you for your help :(

Answer (score 1):

The electric field set up by the polarisation charges would usually be in the *opposite* direction to the applied electric field. However, the polarisation field is *defined* to be in the same direction as the electric field (in linear media). This is the origin of the minus sign.

$$Q_p = -\oint \vec{P}\cdot d\vec{A},$$
where $Q_p$ is the enclosed net polarisation charge and the RHS is minus the closed surface integral of the polarisation field.

Thus if you have an electric field with lines going into a dielectric medium, that will induce negative polarisation charges at the surface even though the polarisation field is in the same direction as the E-field in the medium. Thus the surface charge density is negative.